# Name of Operating Systems used in spaceships?

Tags: operating-systems

I want to know the names of different operating systems used in different spaceships to contol all type of operations including communication, navigation and all others.

Comment: I don't think this is the right site for that.

Comment: A good place to start researching would be [this wiki page about NASA's shuttle programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL/S)

Comment: Way off topic!  They use OSX - see "Independence Day"

Comment: @Chenmunka everyone knows the ID4 aliens invaded prior to the release of OS X. They were still on classic Mac OS.

Comment: There is a space exploration stack exchange. This is probably more suited to that. The answer is going to be "many": VXworks was used in some spacecraft projects, and linux was purportedly used once in a rover project, but they made a big deal about that so it is uncommon.

Comment: Suggest you limit the scope of your question. Are you talking about real life or fictional spacecraft? Forex, the Apollo spacecraft didn't use an OS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Guidance_Computer . The Shuttle's main computers also did not use an OS, although they did carry multiple computers with different OS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle#Flight_systems .

Answer (score 7):

On the starship Enterprise (NCC-1701) the OS is LCARS. It is voice activated with the command "computer". Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCARS)

The Millennium Falcon uses the Hanx-Wargel SuperFlow IV computer, the Rubicon navigation computer and Microaxial HyD modular navigation computer

Comment: I don't think he meant fictional spaceships but actual spaceships like the space shuttles, Saturn V lunar lander, etc.